# Return data-filter onclick possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is it possible to return a specific data-filter from html on click from jquery?

for example:

```
     <div class="container">
        <nav id="filters">
          <ul> 
            <li><a class="all" href="javascript:;" data-filter="all">ALL</a></li>
            <li><a class="americas" href="javascript:;" data-filter="americas">AMERICAS / CARIBBEAN</a></li>
            <li><a class="africa" href="javascript:;" data-filter="africa">AFRICA / MIDDLE EAST</a></li>
            <li><a class="asia" href="javascript:;" data-filter="asia">ASIA / AUSTRALIA </a></li>
          </ul>        
        </nav>
      </div>
```

then in my jquery:

```
$(function clickYoYoYo() {
    $('#yoyoyo').click(function() {
        return ($(this).attr('data-filter="americas"');
    });
});
```

edit: #yoyoyo is a div with a square image

edit2: this is what its suppose to return

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container">
        <ul id="sortlist">
          <li data-filter="americas">
            <p>RETURNED INFO</p>
            <h3 class="countries">Japan</h3>
          </li>
     ...
```

Comment: Where is the element `#yoyoyo`?

Comment: its just a div class with the id name #yoyoyo and its a square block

Comment: Does this element relate to `data-filter` `<li>s`? Are they children of `#yoyoyo`? What do you exactly want on click? The element with `data-filter` = `americas`?

Comment: so when I click #yoyoyo (the square image), it loads the content on the data-filter under america

Comment: you cannot have a named function inside jquery `$(function())` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/p7uyh4m8/) there are many, many errors with this. see fiddle.

Comment: Good catch @yak613! I removed that in my answer without having noticed it in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have three bugs in your code. In your `return` statement, the leading open-parenthesis doesn't have a closing. You can just remove the open-paren as it's unnecessary anyway. Also, remove the `="americas"` from the attribute name. Also, the `clickYoYoYo` function name should be removed (I removed this in my answer, incidentally, but failed to mention it before, as I didn't see it in the OP).

So long as `#yoyoyo` is one of the elements with the `data-filter` attribute then, yes, the following should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('#yoyoyo').click(function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-filter');
    });
})();
```

If `#yoyoyo` is not one of the elements with the `data-filter` attribute, then you will need to use some other logic/selector to tell it which element's `data-filter` to return.

In other words, if you have `#yoyoyo` and you always want to return the `americas` element's filter then you would write:

```
...
$('#yoyoyo').click(function() {
    return $('#filters>ul>li>a.americas').first().attr('data-filter');
});
...
```

As a side-note, if you know that the value of the `data-filter` attribute is not going to change, then you can use `.data('filter')` instead of `.attr('data-filter')`, as the `.data()` call will give you the same thing but will utilize caching. If the filter value can be changed, however, then you should continue to use `.attr()`.

**Update:** 
Based on your comments, I think the you are more looking for one of the following:

```
...
$('#yoyoyo').click(function() {
    return $('#filters>ul>li>a.americas').first().text();
});
...
```

or

```
...
$('#yoyoyo').click(function() {
    return $('#filters>ul>li>a[data-filter="americas"]').first().text();
});
...
```

Comment: assuming theres content in data filter, how am I able to load the specific element in americas?

Comment: How would `data-filter="americas"` be a valid attribute for jQuery to return ? And where does it return to ?

Comment: Thanks @adeneo - I have no idea how I missed that one. Updated :)

Comment: @adeneo, the correct syntax is: `.attr('data-filter', 'americas');` or for just the attribute value, the answer

Comment: the return makes sense to me, but it doesn't seem to return the text in '.americas' when I click on the square (#yoyoyo) and there are no errors on the console... any ideas?

Comment: If you're trying to return the text then you want to return `....first().text();`, not `....first().attr('data-filter');`

Answer (score 0):

The code you've included does not give us enough information to determine what it is you are trying to do. Try explaining the problem in a bit more detail.

Based on your code, it seems that perhaps what you want is that when you click on one of the links in the list, it gives you the value of the `data-filter` attribute so that you can do something with that value. If that's the case, then the simplest approach would be the following:

```
$('#filters').on('click', 'a', function() {
  var filter = $(this).data('filter');
  //do something with the filter variable
});
```

Comment: A few things: 1) he wants to click `#yoyoyo` not `#filters`; 2) introducing a delegated handler here is actually a bad idea, as it has worse performance and isn't necessary (there is a reason why we don't use them for everything); 3) if you're going to change someone's `.attr` call to `.data` then you should disclaim the caching caveat that could cause issues if the value returned gets changed